# Set delimiters with accents

Tags: math-mode, accents, delimiters

I'm trying to set a [set delimiter](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols%3aSet_Operations_and_Relations#Set_Delimiters) using some [mathematical accents](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Accents)
For example:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\left\{{$\hat{P}$,$\hat{Cl}$}\right\}$ 

\end{document}
```

and it fails to compile. I don't know where the error is.

I'm using Texmaker on Linux (if that helps)

Comment: Remove the inner `$` (and use `\widehat` instead of `\hat`)

Comment: @karlkoeller: Not a bad idea i'll globalize \hat to \widehat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is that you are nesting inline math... and it is not allowed.

Also, you should use `\widehat` instead of `\hat` if you want to include more than one character.

I would modify that to (using `article` since I don't have your document class):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\{\widehat{P},\widehat{Cl}\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Surely it can be further improved, but it depends on your taste.

Answer (score 3):

You're opening and closing math mode without a reason.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\left\{\hat{P},\hat{Cl}\right\}$

\end{document}
```

However, the result is really bad

[image]

because the fences are stretched too much. Also “Cl” should be treated in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\{\hat{P},\hat{\mathit{Cl}}\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]